# Embedded expression in XML using karate is not replace data inside CDATA

Tags: karate

Hi I am using Karate frame work for API testing. I need to set the SOAP call payload from another rest call response. I am using embedded expression, that is not working when the expression is inside of the CDATA of the xml. For example SOAP call payload has CDATA like this #(response.Id)</Id>]]>. Embedded expression not replace that "response.Id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if the expression evaluates to a string, you must be doing something wrong. I tested the below code, it works:

```
* def foo = 'hello world'
* def xml = <bar><![CDATA[#(foo)]]></bar>
* match xml = <bar><![CDATA[hello world]]></bar>
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas for your quick response. By the way when I use CDATA as a single(as per the above example) line that is working fine. However my payload has `<soapenv:Envelope><![CDATA<header><id>#(foo)</id></header>]></soapenv:Envelope>`. So I am using multi line with triple quotes. Now embedded expression is not replace the foo. Do I miss anything?

Comment: @user9065498 yes I don't think your CDATA is well formed, it is missing the inner square bracket. also please try the latest released version 0.7.0 - earlier you had to ensure that `foo` was a string, because you have it as XML here.

Comment: @user9065498 and one more thing, you can't mix like this. the WHOLE of the CDATA content should be an embedded expression (it should start with `#(`

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas I am able to resolve the issue.